# Understanding lazy lists in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

My goal is to understand these streams by taking two streams, zipping them together, reversing the order and applying my difference function to make a triple instead of a duple.

For example, applying this function to a stream of odds(1,3,5,7...) and a stream of even numbers(0,2,4,6,8) would yield [(0,1,-1); (2,3,-1); (4,5,-1)] etc etc but it should work with any streams, not just odds and evens-i.e. the third number in the triple will not always be "-1".

```
    type 'x str = Cons of 'x * ('x strm) | Nil
    and  'x strm = unit -> 'x str

    let diff :  int -> int -> int =  fun x y -> x - y

    let rec flip_diff : 'x stream -> 'y stream -> ('x * 'y -> 'z) -> ('y * 'x * 'z) stream =
      fun x y f ->  fun () ->Cons((head y) (head x) (f y x), flip_diff (tail y) (tail x))
```

My error message(to do with the typing) is this:

```
# let rec flip_diff : 'x stream -> 'y stream -> ('x * 'y -> 'z) -> ('y * 'x * 'z) stream =
        fun x y f ->  fun () ->Cons((head y) (head x) (f y x), flip_diff (tail y) (tail x));;
Error: This expression has type
         ('x -> 'a -> 'b) stream = unit -> ('x -> 'a -> 'b) str
       but an expression was expected of type 'x * ('x -> 'a -> 'b)
```

I am honestly having a hard time wrapping my head around the typing. Smaller functions to do with lazy streams are easy, but it's harder to build a function piecewise and then put it together in Ocaml.

Answer (score 0):

Typing is just handling runtime errors before they occur. What the typechecker is saying to you is that this expression is used like it is a stream of functions `('x -> 'a -> 'b) stream` at one place and as a pair `'x * ('x -> 'a -> 'b)` in another place. Since the same object can't be a pair and a function (a stream is a function in your representation), the compiler stops here and asks you to fix your code, which will in runtime (in languages with dynamic typing) crash your program.

The error message also has the pointers that let you identify what `This expression` it means. You didn't provide them so it is hard to guess which in particular expression the compiler meant.

But I can try, first of all, let's look closer at the following expression:

```
Cons((head y) (head x) (f y x), flip_diff (tail y) (tail x))
```

Let's pick the first constituent of the `Cons` pair, namely `(head y) (head x) (f y x)`. As you should already know, functions in OCaml are called by mere juxtaposition, so `f p q` means call `f` with `x` and `y` arguments. Here `f` is `(head y)`, `p` is `(head x)`, and `q` is `f y x`. So the compiler infers, that `y` should be a stream of functions that accepts two arguments, the elements of the first stream `x` and the result of the application of `f x y` where `x` and `y` are streams. So `f` should be a function that takes two streams, but your annotation says that it is a function that is applied to a pair. Already something is wrong. Hint: you probably meant `f (head y, head x)` as you want (if we will treat your own type annotation as your desire) to apply `f` to pairs that are made from elements of `y` and `x` correspondingly.

Another issue with your code is that you call `flip_diff` recursively with one less argument than it expects, e.g., `flip_diff (tail y) (tail x)` while, as your own annotations says us, it accepts three arguments, two streams and the function, e.g., this is what you meant `flip_diff (tail y) (tail x) f` (and probably you don't really want to flip the streams in the recursive call).